# how to add many selected items from checkboxes to listbox at same time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, listbox

I want to be able to add many selected items from a checkbox to a listbox at the same time. This is a sample of the code

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
choice = "Potato soup"
quantity = Val(txtapp1.Text)
price = "80"
If CheckBox2.Checked Then
choice = "Mini tacos"
quantity = Val(txtapp2.Text)
price = "95"
```

I want to be able to add choice, quantity, and price for each checkbox to the listbox at the same time.

Comment: How are you **currently** adding choice, quantity, and price to your listbox?  Are you by chance concatenating them into a **Comma Separated String**?

Comment: @Idle_Mind yes I am.

Comment: I think Alex has the right idea about what you want.  Just add each entry to the listbox within the `if` statement itself.  I'm guessing you were adding the entry at the bottom, below all of your `if` statements, and it was only adding the **last** item that was checked?

Comment: Yes thank you. I was concatenating them with ampersands and some spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your listbox is named ListBoxChoices, the code would be following:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
choice = "Potato soup"
quantity = Val(txtapp1.Text)
price = "80"
ListBoxChoices.Items.Add(choice)
ListBoxChoices.Items.Add(quantity)
ListBoxChoices.Items.Add(price)
End If
If CheckBox2.Checked Then
choice = "Mini tacos"
quantity = Val(txtapp2.Text)
price = "95"
ListBoxChoices.Items.Add(choice)
ListBoxChoices.Items.Add(quantity)
ListBoxChoices.Items.Add(price)
End If
```

Comment: It works but i want it to appear horizontally not vertically.

Comment: the you need to use 3 different list boxes i.e. ListBoxChoice, ListBoxQuantitiy and ListBoxPrice and adjust the Items.add instructions accordingly

Comment: I want them under one listbox so i can transfer it to another listbox for the receipt part.

Comment: could you illustrate this more clearly? maybe draw your desired result and upload it, and there is no horizontal listbox to my information, you could try and rebuild this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752289(v=vs.90).aspx besides that it is even easier to have 3 different data groups and just add them one after each other againif u need that later on

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. i want the items to appear horizontally not vertically.??

Comment: they do appear in my given answer, i dont quite get what you actually want to know now, maybe illustrate it?

Comment: @QadarIsse : Look into the [**`ListView`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx). While the `ListBox` supports multiple columns the `ListView` handles it better.

Comment: You can also add the items separated by **Tabs**.  This does not work as well as a ListView, though.  Something like: `ListBoxChoices.Items.Add(choice & vbTab & quantity & vbTab & price)`